# How can I quickly access the Microsoft Word zoom setting on a Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word, zoom

I get a lot of Word documents to work on, and the first thing I always do is access the zoom setting (View-> Zoom) and change the zoom to "Page Width". There's no keyboard shortcut for the zoom settings, and I do it enough times that I'd like a quicker way. In Pages, there's a little pop-up that lets you choose the zoom you want.

Is there a way to quickly change the zoom settings in Word? Thanks.

Comment: Apple/control with wheel works in Office 2011 for Mac

Comment: None of these are keyboard shortcuts. All require using the mouse (and many mice, including most laptops don't have a scroll wheel). Is there a keyboard shortcut that doesn't require taking your hands off the keyboard?

Comment: I like the selected answer, however, it's also worth noting there are other zoom capabilities available under Universal Access in System Preferences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For MS Word Mac: You zoom by holding the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key while scrolling the mouse wheel. 
http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070113120847965

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Never would have found it by trial and error.

Comment: Mac's use of modifier keys never ceases to amaze - thanks.

Comment: The CTRL key alone is sufficient in Lion 10.7.5 with Word 2011 v14.2.5

Answer (score 6):

On my Macbook Air, I can hold "control" and "command" and slide two fingers on the touchpad down and up to zoom in and out, respectively, within Microsoft Word 2011.

Comment: Except you don't need to hold CMND, only CTRL.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which version of Word you are using you can hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and use the scroll wheel (or whichever button you use to scroll!) and this will zoom in and out.

This works with a lot of other Microsoft applications.

Comment: yep i use this shortcut for internet browsers a lot too like Firefox and Internet Explorer

Answer (score 3):

In the 2011 version, I just selected `Tools` → `Customize Keyboard`, and under view I selected viewzoompagewidth and set a custom keyboard shortcut. I chose <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

In other words, while holding <kbd>command</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>, press the <kbd>right arrow</kbd> and <kbd>left arrow</kbd> keys.

Comment: Wow, I never knew; that is extremely helpful, thanks!  Now I have command-= and command-- working in Word just like those keystrokes work in every other os x app, thank you!

Comment: didn't work... but Control + wheel works great !

Comment: Confirmed with Office 2016 Mac Version 15.33 (170409), I assigned mine to Command + Control + 2, similar to cmd+2 (fit width) in Acrobat reader

Answer (score 1):

I found that another way to do this is to customize the toolbar. I wasn't displaying the standard toolbar, where there is a zoom drop-down menu. I right-clicked on the toolbar that I was displaying (Formatting) and clicked "Customize toolbars and menus". On the "Commands" tab, I dragged the zoom button from "View" out on to my toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually default keyboard shortcuts for zoom in (Control Option -) and zoom out (Control Option =), at least for English Canadian keyboard. For keyboards where + and = don't share the same key, I'd try Control Option + for zooming in.

Edit: I am not sure anymore whether this is actually a default shortcut; both of my machines have it but not the one of my colleague so maybe I have set that at some point in the past... (sorry if that's the case)

Comment: Don't you mean Command, instead of Control, on the Mac?